# select where column contains hebrew letters

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table with more than 300k rows and a column `name`, the column name may be only in English or only Hebrew or Hebrew and English.
I'm trying to write the right query to get rows with only Hebrew or Hebrew and English. The row must contains any Hebrew letter.
I tried to write the following query:

```
 select * from table_name where `name` regex '^[א-ת]+$';
```

so it would begin and end with Hebrew letters but it's still returns rows with only English. any suggestions for the right regex to write?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I can point out two problems with your approach.  First, mysql regexps [don't know about multibyte characters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#idm140307232984976), they always match single bytes.  Second, even if they did, ranges of multibyte character sets are always problematic (for obvious reasons, if you think about them for a few minutes: locale collations are _way_ more complicated than any kind of byte sorting).  I don't think any of the existing regexp engine can handle this in a reasonable way for generic locales.

Comment: so the only solution is to run over all the rows and in php check if it contains hebrew letters ? i wanted to spare rows that i select

Comment: Or you can use negated set `^[^a-zA-Z]+$` to select rows other than English words :)

Comment: @Maisam Mansour: Like I said, I don't have a real solution.  I suppose matching the individual hebrew letters could work, but I doubt it would do that in reasonable time.  If it's only a one-off operation you need to do, it might be better to dump your database to a text file and try your luck with shell scripts.

Comment: @karthik manchala: What about spaces?  Punctuation?  Are you sure the byte representation of hebrew letters don't include ASCII characters?

Comment: "words" does not contain spaces or punctuations.. and logically byte representation of  hebrew letters should not include ASCII characters

Comment: i found an intersting solution : 
select * from table where char_length(`name`)<>length(`name`)
where length function returns in bytes and char_length count chars @Icd047

Comment: @Maisam Mansour: Nice. I think using something like `a|b|c|...|z` (with Hebrew letters instead of the Latin ones) instead of a `[...]` range might also work.  Basically, this identifies Hebrew letters with the corresponding two bytes sequences.

Comment: @karthik manchala: There is at least one Asian charset where byte representations of _all_ letters are two bytes, and both bytes are within the ASCII range.  Does this affect representations of Hebrew letters?  I don't know, and I can't be bothered to find out.  But you shouldn't just assume `[^a-zA-Z]` catches interesting characters.  There is at least one situation where this doesn't work. _shrug_

Comment: @lcd047 agreed... Thats a point to consider.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
select * from table_name where `name` regex '^[^a-zA-Z]+$'
```

Comment: Nope, mysql regexps don't know about multibyte characters.

Comment: You have a typo in surrounding quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE ( name REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z]+$'
     OR HEX(name) REGEXP '^(D7..)+$' )
```

Notes

- This assumes `name` has `CHARACTER SET` utf8 or utf8mb4.
- All utf8 encodings for Hebrew letters are hex D7xx.  Some non-letter Hebrew codes are D7xx, D6xx, and even EFxxyy.  Try `SELECT name, HEX(name) FROM tbl WHERE HEX(name) LIKE '%D6%' to see if you get anything.
- The regexp does not allow for spaces.  '^(D7..|20)+$' should allow spaces in the Hebrew.

There is a `CHARACTER SET hebrew` with a default `COLLATION hebrew_general_ci`, plus `hebrew_bin`.  It contains English letters, and is single-byte.